# Property injection in the base class does not work

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection

My problem is that a bean is not being injected in the base class. I read many questions and answers about this topic but none did really help me.

I have an abstract base class with a property that shall be injected:

```
public abstract class AbstractResearchService<R extends ResearchResult, S extends PredictionResult> {
    @EJB(lookup = ResearchManager.JNDI_BINDING)
    private ResearchManager researchManager;

    protected R submit(final ResearchQuery query) {
        // researchManager is null here
    }
```

The inheriting child class is a stateless bean implementing a remote interface:

```
@Stateless
@Remote(VoyageResearchService.class)
@WebService(...)
public class VoyageResearchServiceBean extends AbstractResearchService<VoyageResearchResult, VoyagePredictionResult>
    implements VoyageResearchService {

    @Override
    public VoyageResearchResult submitQuery(final VoyageResearchQuery query) {
        return submit(query);
    }
}
```

This is the bean with its interface that shall be injected:

```
@Local
public interface ResearchManager {
    String JNDI_BINDING = "java:global/omd-research-manager/ResearchManagerBean";

    ResearchResult submitQuery(ResearchQuery query);
}

@Singleton
@Startup
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.BEAN)
public class ResearchManagerBean implements ResearchManager {
    ...
}
```

I searched for the issue and found multiple statements:

1. Dependency injection in base classes does work.
2. The inheriting class must be container managed to make injection work.

Can you confirm these statements?

Since my VoyageResearchServiceBean is being instantiated by the container (due to the @Stateless annotation) I am wondering why the injection doesn't work. When the submit() method is being called, the property researchManager is null.

What I have tried:

When I inject the researchManager into the child class it works fine. But since I only need it in the base class, I would like to inject it there.

When I try to use setter injection:

```
@Inject
public void setResearchManager(final ResearchManager researchManager) {
    this.researchManager = researchManager;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ResearchManager with qualifiers @Default                                                                                            
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Inject public com.in.omd.researchmanager.AbstractResearchService.setResearchManager(ResearchManager)
```

Can you please give me an advice what is going wrong here or what I am overlooking? Thanks for your help in advance.